# Выделить жирным выводимый ботом текст

Tags: python, telebot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: хочу, чтобы бот выводил выделенный текст, но он выводит его с двумя звездочками спереди и сзади. В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    k1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Привет', callback_data = 'load_test')
    markup.add(k1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '**Привет**!', reply_markup = markup)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать HTML разметку сообщения, используя тэг `<b>Привет</b>!` и отправляя его с параметром `parse_mode='HTML'` в методе `send_message`

Comment: добавь ``parse_mode="MarkdownV2"`` или ``parse_mode="Markdown"``

Answer (score 3):

## **Вариант 1 - ЧЕРЕЗ HTML РАЗМЕТКУ**

Используйте HTML-разметку для формирования различного форматирования текста, в данном случае вам подойдет тэг `<b> </b>`, а при отправке сообщения через `send_message` используйте параметр `parse_mode='HTML'`. Ваш код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = 'ВАШ ТОКЕН'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    k1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Привет', callback_data = 'load_test')
    markup.add(k1)
    # формируем сообщение жирным шрифтом через HTML тэг
    message_text = "<b>Привет</b>!"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, reply_markup = markup, parse_mode='HTML')

bot.polling()
```

Результат будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## **Вариант 2 - ЧЕРЕЗ MarkdownV2**

По сути передавая в качестве параметра `parse_mode='MarkdownV2'` в `send_message` мы можем использовать `MarkdowvnV2` разметку, которая обладает своими правилами в оформлении. Мы должны обязательно экранировать восклицательный знак `!`, так как данный символ является инструкцией для `MarkdownV2`.

Ваш код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = 'ВАШ ТОКЕН'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    k1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Привет', callback_data = 'load_test')
    markup.add(k1)
    # экранируем восклицательный знак и формируем через MarkdownV2 как жирный шрифт
    message_text = "*Привет\\!*" 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, reply_markup = markup, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')

bot.polling()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

P.S.
Если кому-то показалось, что шрифт не жирный, сравним в двух методах.

- **HTML разметка:**

```
...
    message_text = "<b>Привет</b>! и обычный привет"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, reply_markup = markup, parse_mode='HTML')
...
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можем видеть, первый `Привет` в жирном шрифте, другой в обычном, аналогично ниже.

- **MarkdownV2 разметка:**

```
...
    message_text = "*Привет\\!* и обычный привет" 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, reply_markup = markup, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
...
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то не похоже, что выделено жирным

Comment: @Эникейщик добавил по вашему комментарию сравнительные примеры

Comment: ну да, так заметнее